# issues with complex number in VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, new-operator, complex-numbers

```
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

mx_vector = new double [NX]; //NX = 200
imx_vector = new complex<double> [NX];

i = 1;
imx_vector[i].real () = 0.0;
imx_vector[i].imag () = mx_vector[i]; //mx_vector[i] = 2.2

//This is part of a big program, so hiding the simple details like main() etc.
```

Hi, I have this code and was working well with intel c++ in redhat linux. Now when I compile it in VS 2010 I get the error "error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value".
I have looked up the MSDN ref, previous posts on stackflow but couldnt fix it.
Is there something to do with "new"?

Any help/reference will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`imx_vector[i].real()` as well as `imx_vector[i].imag()` return the `double`, not `double&`.

You probably meant (*C++98*):

```
imx_vector[i] = std::complex<double>(0.0, mx_vector[i]);
```

or (*C++11*):

```
imx_vector[i].real(0.0);
imx_vector[i].imag(mx_vector[i]);
```

Comment: Awesome !, The second version did the trick. Thanks a ton...