# std::complex<float> with error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value

Tags: c++, vector, stl, complex-numbers

I performed fast Fourier transform (fft) on my `signal`, turning it into `signalComplex`; `signal` is a series of real float numbers and `signalComplex` represents a series of complex numbers:

```
std::vector<std::complex<float>> signalComplex(numSamplesPerScan);   // int numSamplesPerScan

    fft.fwd(signalComplex, signal);    //  std::vector<float> signal

    for (int n = 1; n < numSamplesPerScan / 2; n++)   // simplified procedure to calculate HT
    {
        float real = signalComplex[n].real();   // positive frequency X 2
        float imag = signalComplex[n].imag();

        real *= 2;
        imag *= 2;

        signalComplex[n].real() = real;  // compiler complains here
        signalComplex[n].imag() = imag;  // compiler complains here

        signalComplex[n + numSamplesPerScan / 2].real() = 0;    // compiler complains here
        signalComplex[n + numSamplesPerScan / 2].imag() = 0;    // compiler complains here
    }
```

In the for loop above, I am trying to do some simple computation on real and imaginary parts of the `signalComplex`. However, the compiler complains about "**error C2106: '=': left operand must be l-value**"; I am not sure how to do computation on the real imaginary parts in this case.

Any pointer is appreciated. Some code is highly appreciated.

Comment: `real()` and `imag()` return floats by value, not references to the internal parts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to directly assign complex numbers to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169567/how-to-directly-assign-complex-numbers-to-a-variable)

Comment: @Brian Thanks Brian. It works. Do you want to post the answer, which I prefer? Or I can post what I did.

Comment: Check out https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex Array Oriented Access. There is a special provision for complex numbers that allows direct access which would otherwise be UB.

Comment: Simplify! Do you need a vector and all the background information just to get the compilation error? Break your compound expression into simpler pieces, as in `auto x = signalComplex[n]; x.real() = real;` Now that the error is on the line `x.real() =real;`, deduce the type of `x` and drop the rest of your code: `int main() { std::complex<float> x; x.real() = real; }`. Much easier to reason about, no?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [issues with complex number in VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713825/issues-with-complex-number-in-vs-2010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank all people here that were trying to help me.

Like Brian pointed out, the code in the questions is modified to

```
std::vector<std::complex<float>> signalComplex(numSamplesPerScan);

fft.fwd(signalComplex, signal);

for (int n = 1; n < numSamplesPerScan / 2; n++)   
{
    signalComplex[n] = { signalComplex[n].real()*2, signalComplex[n].imag()*2 };  // following is the key part
    signalComplex[n + numSamplesPerScan / 2] = {0, 0};
}
```

and it compiles just fine.